# SELECT INTO OUTFILE two tables with condition error

Tags: mysql, export, union, file-io

I am trying to export the results of my query to a file as a report. I am using two tables.

Here's an example code:

`SELECT 'Test1','Test2','Test3','First Name','Last Name'`

`UNION ALL`

`SELECT TESTS.TEST1, TESTS.TEST2, TESTS.TEST3, STUDENT.FNAME, STUDENT.LNAME`

`WHERE TESTS.Student_S_ID = STUDENT.S_ID`

`INTO OUTFILE /path/'Records'`

`FROM TEST, STUDENT;`

I'm getting a syntax error for the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are jumbled. The syntax is:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
INTO OUTFILE ...
```

Your `FROM` is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FROM` needs to be moved before the `where`.